# javascript, Converting or Casting an object

Tags: javascript, types, casting, type-conversion, prototype

how to type cast or convert objects in java script ?

for example

```
var e = document.getElementById('body'); // e is instance of HTMLBodyElement
e = <type cast to HTMLElement> e ; // e is instance of HTMLElement
```

Comment: There is no such concept in JavaScript or with DOM elements in browsers. You can create an element and with your own code copy property values into it.

Comment: What are you trying to do that you think you need to cast for?  We can probably help you with that once we understand your desired result.

Comment: Everything is just a giant property bag in Javascript.  `x.y` is just a shortcut for `x['y']`

Comment: It should be noted that `document.body instanceof HTMLElement === true`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about conversion of html body in HTML element, first it is part of html and second in Javascript there is no such categorization one should try the same in VB script.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, I think you need to try this

```
var e = document.getElementById('body'); // e is instance of HTMLBodyElement
e = $(e);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to cast. A HTMLBodyElement is derived from a HTMLElement and therefore can be used as if it is a HTMLElement. 
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLBodyElement specifically where it says:
  "*Inherits properties from its parent, HTMLElement and from WindowEventHandlers.*"